# Error: HTTP service "BdcService" too busy

Tags: central-administration, bdc

I am trying to access the bdc-service of a sharepoint server via central administration. This is getting me the error:

> The HTTP service located at http://[servername]:32843/c023cc02807443888f0bac997c7f5185/BdcService.svc/http is too busy.

I did a lot of google research but could not find a way to get it going.

- I found a corresponding service with the GUID c023cc02807443888f0bac997c7f5185 in site "sharepoint web services" in IIS, but when browsing it, got the 503 error ("service unavailable").
- I restarted the site and it´s application pool ("sharepoint web services root") in IIS, and also the bdc service in the central administration, without success.
- Checked the identity of the application pool and the service account for the bdc-service in central administration: they are the same. Not sure if it is important but had read that in some blog entry.

Comment: I have seen similar issues, do you have more than one BDC Service Application Instance in the Farm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application pool of the bdc service had stopped. I incorrectly had assumed that the service uses the pool "sharepoint web services root" while it in fact uses some other pool with a GUID. This pool I also had restarted, but it always stopped becauses the password of the identity user had changed.

Comment: Thanks Gerald! As you mentioned, the affected application pool also had a GUID type name which was not very helpful in diagnosing. This application pool stated 'Started' but would not stop because "it was not started". Changing the login credentials forced the Application Pool to stop. I was then able to start the service. Everything worked ok for a few minutes, but now the error has recurred. :-(